# Dynamic Variable in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have an environmental variable defined in my pipeline. I am trying to define a variable dynamically based on the variable defined in the `environment` block.

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   environment {
     field = 'customfield_123'
   }
   stages {
      steps {
        script {

     def details = new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClasssic().parseText(file)
     def data = details.fields."env.field".slipt()
     }
    }
   }
 }
```

How will this be possible? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I had to ensure the variable was evaluated.

```
...
def data = details.fields."${env.field}".split()
...
```